# How do I create and modify application launchers in the Unity dash in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, launcher, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

I want to add commands to the Unity dash and the launcher, so that I can can press Super and type the name of my command to launch it, or click on the left launcher icon, or use Kupfer to launch it. Surprisingly, I can't figure out how to do this. In previous Ubuntu versions, there was a settings app called "Main Menu" where you could edit the list of programs.

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand